# About installing Theano

Tags: machine-learning, visualization, data-mining, theano

I hope this question is relevant to this community as Theano is increasingly a standard software to do machine learning.

---

So I have been trying to follow the instructions here,
http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows to install Theano on my Windows machine but as expected I am stuck with various parts.

So I have created a folder called "Theano" and in that I have 3 folders which have installed ``Theano-0.8.2" , GCC and Anaconda.

- I am following the "Alternative:Anaconda" route and there I am instructed to type into my Windows command prompt, "conda install mingw libpython". But on doing that I get this message saying that `mingw" and` python 3.5*" specifications are in conflict.

  What does this mean? What is ``mingw"!?
- In the "Configuring The Environment" section what is this "PATH" that is being talked about? Do I have to write this ``shell script"? (What is this?) Where does one write this and save this file?

  Can someone show a generic version of this script in which I can maybe fill in the blanks corresponding to how my folders are organized? (The .bat file that they have written seems to correspond to their file structure and its hardly clear as to which parts change!)
- Then further down one sees this section, "Configuring Theano" it asks one to open a "Python Shell" and run the command "python setup.py develop".

  So what is the "Python Shell"? Where do I find it?
  Is it that black "Anaconda Prompt" terminal?

---

To be clear now when I open my "Anaconda Prompt" window it says,

< C:\Users(my_user_name)\Theano\Anaconda > C:\Users(my_user_name)>

Seeing this I thought that Theano is now installed.
But when I open the Jupyter notebook and type "import theano", I get an error!

Comment: FYI  [How to install Theano on Anaconda Python 2.7 x64 on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33687103/395857)

Comment: Have a look at our [help/on-topic] to see what is considered on-topic here - this seems to be a question exclusively about installing software rather than an underlying statistical issue

Comment: Do feel free to migrate this to the stackexchange where you think this might be more appropriate!

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate for StackExchange's Data Science forum, which is still technically in Beta but gets a lot of traffic. They cater more to the programming side of machine learning, which is probably why there are tons of posts there about the ins and outs of Theano.